# Spam Bot Help Needed - Rails ApplicationController Quick Solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not able to use rack-attack. My Ruby is < 2.0. I tried. Just real quick I would like to do something in ApplicationController.

I have a spam bot right now that comes periodically. I know the ip. In application controller I can just check `if request.remote_ip == "52.3.127.199"` but then what? Is there something I can do to just return say a string `"x"` that way it doesn't tear up my app.

My app runs on 1 dyno on Heroku and its killing it.

What is best quick dirty fix?

Comment: For now I am just doing this is a before_filter in ApplicationController `if request.remote_ip == "52.3.127.199 redirect_to my_path"`

My path is a simple page that doesn't take much to render. My normal pages are very very data heavy.

Comment: This is even better to stop a spam bot in your ApplicationController `raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') `if ["52.3.127.1xx"].include?(request.remote_ip)`

Answer (score 0):

what is the bot doing or trying to do? Something as simple as changing a css selector on an input could work. Other things to try: `before_filter` that checks for that IP and just returns if the request is from that IP.